# What is the purpose of the $AUTHORITY variable in a Perl CPAN distribution?

Tags: perl, cpan, dist-zilla

According to [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Authority](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Authority) :

> This plugin adds the authority data to your distribution. It adds the
> data to your modules and metadata. Normally it looks for the PAUSE
> author id in your Dist::Zilla configuration.

What is the *"authority data"* used for? Why is it added to all the modules?

See also [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::PERLANCAR::Authority](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PERLANCAR/Dist-Zilla-Plugin-PERLANCAR-Authority-0.001/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/PERLANCAR/Authority.pm)

Comment: I think it's for [this module](https://metacpan.org/pod/authority)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Raku, a module (actually any type) can have [attributes](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem) `:ver<>`, `:auth<>` and `:api<>`. This allows you to pass it a version, author, and/or API number, which you can subsequently introspect.

```
class C:ver<4.2.3>:auth<github:jane>:api<1> {}
say C.^auth;      # OUTPUT: «github:jane»
```

In Perl, the authority of a package can be defined like this:

```
package MyApp;
BEGIN { $MyApp::AUTHORITY = 'cpan:JOEBLOGGS'; }
```

The authority should be an URI identifying the person, team, or organisation responsible for the release of the package. The pseudo-URI scheme `cpan:` is the most commonly used identifier.

The `$AUTHORITY` package variable can be used together with the [authority](https://metacpan.org/pod/authority) pragma to load a module conditionally based on its authority:

```
use authority 'cpan:JOE', My::Module => qw();
```

Assuming that the `@INC` path is `/opt/perl/lib`, then Perl will attempt to load `/opt/perl/lib/cpan_3A_JOE/My/Module.pm` before it tries the usual `/opt/perl/lib/My/Module.pm`.

Also having a defined `$AUTHORITY`, enables module authority introspection with [UNIVERSAL::AUTHORITY::Lexical](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL::AUTHORITY::Lexical). For example:

```
use UNIVERSAL::AUTHORITY::Lexical;
if (HTML::HTML5::Writer->AUTHORITY ne HTML::HTML5::Builder->AUTHORITY)
{
  warn "Closely intertwined modules with different authors!\n";
  warn "There may be trouble ahead...";
}
```

and

```
use UNIVERSAL::AUTHORITY::Lexical;
# Only trust STEVAN's releases
Moose->AUTHORITY('cpan:STEVAN'); # dies if doesn't match
```

See also [our $AUTHORITY](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=694377) for the original discussion on this variable.